# Get the ID of the current user using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I want to get the ID of the current user using REST API. 
This is the function:

```
 function ReturnIDUser(url) {
            //Url should be _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
            // var item = getListItems(url, listName, customquery, '', '');
            //ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Start, "sp.js");
            var Result = null;

            $.ajax({

                url:url+"/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getmyproperties",
                type: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {

                    Result = data.d;
                    ////get login name  
                    //var loginName = Result.LoginName.split('|')[1];
                    //alert(loginName);
                    ////get display name
                    //alert(Result.Title);
                    //

                },
                async: false,
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
            return Result.Id;
        }
```

But it's always error, this is the error:

> responseText  "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1,
>   System.InvalidProgramException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\"
>                 :\"Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.\"},\"innererror\":{\"message\":\"Common Language Runtime
>   detected an invalid program.
>                 \",\"type\":\"System.InvalidProgramException\",\"stacktrace\":\"
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PeopleManager.GetMyProperties()\r\n
>
> at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PeopleManagerServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, String methodName, ClientValueCollection xmlargs,
>                 ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object
>   target, String methodName, 
>                 ClientValueCollection args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)\r\n 
>                 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.InvokeMethod(Boolean
>   mainRequestPath, Object value, ServerStub serverProxy, EdmParserNode
>   node,
>                 Boolean resourceEndpoint, MethodInformation methodInfo, Boolean isExtensionMethod, Boolean isIndexerMethod)\r\n 
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.GetObjectFromPathMember(Boolean
>   mainRequestPath, String path, Object value, EdmParserNode node,
>                 Boolean resourceEndpoint, MethodInformation& methodInfo)\r\n
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.GetObjectFromPath(Boolean
>   mainRequestPath, String path, String pathForErrorMessage)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.Process()\r\n 
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest()\r\n
>
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestService.ProcessQuery(Stream
>   inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)\"}}}"

Comment: Do you still get the error if you just use this (in javascript console for example)?: `$.getJSON("/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getmyproperties", function(data) { console.log(data) })`

Comment: Why don't you update your previous question with these details?